# Separar Array PHP para insercion BD

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" name="permiso[]" data- 
color="#99d683" data-secondary-color="#f96262" data-size="small" 
value="'.$item.','.$id_user.'" /> </td>';
```

Donde $item son los id de unos permisos de unos procesos.
Donde $id_user son los id de los usuarios seleccionados con los permisos anteriores.

Esto se envia por POST a la pagina que procesara las peticiones y guardara en la BD (procesador.php). En procesador.php, recibo ese array de esta manera:

```
$permiso = implode(",", $_POST['permiso']);
```

Imprimo estos valores para ver que esta todo OK y me da esto:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "2,9" [1]=> string(4) "4,19" }
```

Donde el array 0 lleva el 2 (id del proceso) y 9 (id usuario).
Donde el array 1 lleva el 4 (id del proceso) y 19 (id usuario).
Cabe señalar que estos array son dinamicos y pueden contener un permiso con un usuario o varios permisos con varios usuarios.

La primera pregunta ante todo, esta bien construido el array?
La segunda pregunta, como puedo separar cada array y asignarlo a variables dinamicas para insertar id de proceso en campo permiso e id usuario en campo id_user de mi tabla de la base de datos?

Por ej:

$var1 = 'id proceso';
$var2 = 'id usuario';

Nota: !!Los valores que se envian por POST, son los checkbox que se han clickeado!!

Como siempre, agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientacion al respecto.
Si hay alguna duda con respecto a mi pregunta, con gusto la respondere.
Saludos y gracias a todos.

Comment: Simplemente quieres añadir los valores de ese array en dos campos en la base de datos?

Comment: a dos campos? idCampo1 =0  idCampo1 = 9 , idCampo1 =4  idCampo1 = 19 ¿eso quieres insertar?

Comment: pienso que los estas trayendo mal o insertando  desde un principio esto deberias traer de la base e igual enviar al modelo.  array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "2,9"} , array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "4,19"} , si quieres te puedo poner un ejemplo que hice es muy parecido al tuyo

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder.. Lo que pasa es que esos arrays contienen 2 datos, el id del proceso y el id de usuario por cada array. En mi tabla tengo: id_permiso | id usuario y se deberia insertar asi ( ej):
    --------------------------------
    |id_proceso | id_usuario|
    --------------------------------
       2          |       9
    --------------------------------
       4          |      19
    -------------------------------

Si fuesen array fijos no habria problema, pero como son dinamicos, no se como separarlos y pasarlos a variables o alguna otra forma para insercion

Comment: pero tu los estas trayendo en un solo array los dos si no estas usando una tabla intermedia pienso que esta mal la logica , debes traer solo id proceso= 2,4 idusaurio = 9,19

Comment: despues tienes que hacer el foreach  para mostrar  idproceso = 2, idUsuario = 9 , idproceso = 4, idUsuario = 19  no se piensalo a lo mejor estoy mal

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil claro, por eso una de mis preguntas iniciales era si lo estaba haciendo de forma correcta o erronea. Lo que me planteas seria lo ideal. Ahora, como envio desde mi value segun tu propuesta? Gracias por la info.

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil la verdad no estimado. Si tienes algun ejemplo para poder aplicarlo a mi codigo, te lo agradeceria muchisimo.

Comment: ahi te puse un ejemplo, tienen que ser dos array diferentes, no puedes enviarlo en uno solo mismo , aparte tienen que tener la misma cantidad de valores cada array, por que si envias 123 y 9876  podras utilizar  123 y 987  pero que pasa con el 6?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77952/discussion-between-carlos-enrique-gil-gil-and-maha1982).

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil si por supuesto, te estaba hablando por alla. Gracias y saludos

Comment: Si he entendido bien, tú quieres insertar esos valores en la base de datos ¿es correcto?. Si es así, lo más importante es que indiques **cómo sería la consulta de inserción** que debes construir a partir de los datos. En base a eso entonces se te podrá decir si conviene que el array esté  construido como lo tienes ahora o si conviene construirlo de otra forma. Si la SQL de inserción es parecida a esto: `INSERT INTO tu-tabla (id_proceso, id_usuario) VALUES (2,9), (4,19)` entonces tu array está perfecto como lo tienes. Sólo hay que darle lógica al código para que tome los datos y los inserte.

Answer (score 0):

alta vista

```
             <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                <label class="control-label">Disponibilidad</label>
                <div>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Lunes">
                    Lu
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Martes" >
                    Ma
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Miercoles">
                    Mie
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Jueves" >
                    Jue
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" checked value="Viernes">
                    Vie
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" value="Sabado" >
                    Sa
                  </label>
                  <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" value="Domingo" >
                    D
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
```

controlador

```
case "guardar":
                        $resultado = $this->varSolicitudEmpleo -> guardar($_POST["Datos"],$_POST["diasTrabajados"],$_POST["paquestesLenguajes"],$_POST["promocion"],$_POST["conocimientos"],$_POST["habilidades"]);
                        echo $resultado;
                        $_SESSION["spar_error"] = "Se agregó el perfil correctamente.";
                    break;
```

modelo

```
public function guardar($datos,$diasTrabajados,$paquestesLenguajes,$promocion,$conocimientosEspecificos,$habilidades){

if(isset($diasTrabajados)){
        $diasTrabajados1 = implode(",", $diasTrabajados);
        $diasTrabajados1 = $this->conexion -> real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($diasTrabajados1))));
        }else{
            $diasTrabajados1 = NULL;
        }
}
```

modal editar vista

```
 <?php $diasTrabajados = explode(",", $solicitudEmpleo['diasTrabajados']); ?>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label class="control-label">Disponibilidad</label>
                          <div>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" <?php if(in_array('Lunes', $diasTrabajados)){ echo 'checked';} ?> value="Lunes">
                              Lu
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" <?php if(in_array('Martes', $diasTrabajados)){ echo 'checked';} ?> value="Martes" >
                              Ma
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" <?php if(in_array('Miercoles', $diasTrabajados)){ echo 'checked';} ?> value="Miercoles">
                              Mie
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" <?php if(in_array('Jueves', $diasTrabajados)){ echo 'checked';} ?> value="Jueves" >
                              Ju
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" <?php if(in_array('Viernes', $diasTrabajados)){ echo 'checked';} ?> value="Viernes">
                              Vie
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" <?php if(in_array('Sabado', $diasTrabajados)){ echo 'checked';} ?> value="Sabado" >
                              Sa
                            </label>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                              <input type="checkbox" name="diasTrabajados[]" class="flat-red" <?php if(in_array('Domingo', $diasTrabajados)){ echo 'checked';} ?> value="Domingo" >
                              Do
                            </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

controlador

```
if(!isset($_POST["diasTrabajados"])){$_POST["diasTrabajados"] =NULL; }
$resultado = $this->varSolicitudEmpleo->actualizar($_POST["Datos"],$_POST["diasTrabajados"],$_POST["paquestesLenguajes"],$_POST["promocion"],$_POST["conocimientos"],$_POST["habilidades"]);
```

modelo actualizar

```
public function actualizar($datos,$diasTrabajados,$paquestesLenguajes,$promocion,$conocimientosEspecificos,$habilidades){ if(isset($diasTrabajados)){       
$diasTrabajados1 = implode(",", $diasTrabajados);       $diasTrabajados1 = $this->conexion -> real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($diasTrabajados1))));         }else{          $diasTrabajados1 = NULL;        } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para el array yo usaría algo como

```
$miarray = array
(
 array(2,9),
 array(4,19)
);
```

luego podrías accederlo así

```
$var1 = $miarray[0][0]; //id proceso
$var2 = $miarray[0][1]; //id usuario
```